# Непонятен принцип работы текущей базы данных

Tags: postgresql

В БД имеются 3 таблицы: У каждой из них поле id является primary key

| Orders | Users | Countries |
| --- | --- | --- |
| id | id | id |
| user_id | registered_at | full_name |
| transaction | country_id | iso |
| finished_at | campaign |  |

В таблице Orders на каждый user_id приходится много записей в поле transaction. Вопрос следующий, как может работать такая база данных? Ведь поле id(primary key) обязано быть уникальным и в таблице Orders будут создаваться много уникальных id для которых не будет соответствия в других таблицах?

Например у нас есть 10 пользователей, каждый из которых совершил по 10 транзакций. И тогда в таблице Orders у нас будет 100 записей, но в таблице Users и Countries будет всего 10, если я правильно понимаю описанное мной устройство данной БД. Так ли это?

Comment: Всё верно - поле `id` уникально *в своей* таблице.

Answer (score 0):

Поля `id` из разных таблиц не имеют к друг другу отношения.

Пользователь с номером 1 (т.е. запись в таблице `Users` со значением поля `id==1`), может не иметь ничего общего з заказом номер 1 (т.е. с записью в `Orders` со значением 1 в поле `id`). Заказ номер 1, вполне возможно, сделал пользователь номер 8 (или какой-то другой).

Значения в поле `id` у разных записей в таблице `Users` (как и в других) действительно уникальны. Как раз для того, чтоб указав идентификатор (или по другому "номер"), можно было точно понять, о какой записи (пользователе идет речь).

Comment: А как в таком случае сджойнить эти 3 таблицы или 2 из них? Если поле id в 3-х таблицах может не иметь ничего общего, а других общих полей у таблиц нет. Например если я хочу, вывести количество пользователей по месяцам, которые совершили транзакцию( это таблица Orders) в том же месяце, что и зарегистрировались (это таблица Users)?

Comment: Почему же нет общих полей. `user_id` в `Orders` наверняка ссылается на `id` из `Users`. Делайте join по `Orders.user_id == Users.id`.